# What is the best way to "overload" a field in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model, overloading

Consider a model user:

```
User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, status: string)
```

When I built the application, status was a field in the database. But new requirements means a change so that status is dynamically calculated in some cases. For example, on Sundays, if their last name starts with A, then their status is "not ok".

I want to encapsulate this functionality in the User model with ***something like the following***:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def status
    if is_sunday && last_name.starts_with('A')
        return 'not ok'
    else
       return status
    end
  end

end
```

What is the best way to do this? If the above code does work, it seems bad practice to override the field in the database with a method.

Alternatively, I could create a method `get_status` to use the above code. But in this case I need to change every reference to `status` throughout the application. That doesn't sound good.

Comment: fwiw, I am completely okay with that method as a solution. I think that adding `get_status` is more confusing because you're kinda creating a second way of retrieving the User's status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen in the [ActiveRecord::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Overwriting+default+accessors) that you can override default accessors provided by ActiveRecord. Of course you can't use `status` as you do because it makes the method somewhat recursive.

You can access the column value in the DB by using `read_attribute(:attribute_name)` or `self[:attribute_name]` if you prefer. So long story short, your accessor becomes:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def status
    if is_sunday && last_name.starts_with('A')
      'not ok'
    else
      read_attribute(:status)
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**: I've tried it and it works but pay attention because if you don't call this method explicitly you get the DB content...for example you try to query the `users` table to find users with `status = "not ok"` you could have surprises.

Comment: On Rails 3.2, does replacing `return read_attribute(:status)` with `super` work for you?

Comment: `super` should work even in previous Rails version since it's a Ruby keywork but it seems a bit ambiguous to me in this context. I would prefer to make this explicit.

Comment: the `return` are not necessary of course, I've used it to match the question (removed now), I personally don't dislike it too much but "the else branch" seems cleaner without the `return`